# ion-list vs ion-scroll vs virtualScroll in ionic 3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I want to show a list in Ionic 3. Data is coming from server. So I used ion-list with ngFor. This way all items are rendered at once and scrolling is not very smooth.

Then I used virtual scroll as follows:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="hotelsarray" approxItemHeight="220px">
    <div tappable *virtualItem="let hotel" class="item-inner-hotel">
    <-- Other Code -->
```

But now no item is rendered at all. Many virtualScroll issue at Github.

Then I decided to use ion-scroll instead of ion-list. Now scrolling is very fast & smooth. But I also want to listen for scrollStarted & scrollEnd events which is not in ion-scroll.

So, what should I do to achieve following:
- To show a list with images & text in items.
- Scrolling should be fast & smooth.
- ScrollStart & scrollEnd event, I want to listen for.
- There should also be a scrollTo(x, y, time) like method, so that I can scroll to any specific item.

Edit: This is only for iOS. In android, ion-list with ngFor is working fine & scrolling is also good.

Edit2: Pasting ts code:

```
public hotelsarray: any; //declaration
this.hotelsarray = []; // in constructor
this.hotelsarray = data.results; //after http call
```

Edit3: Pasting html snippet:

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="hotelsarray" approxItemHeight="220px">
    <ion-item *virtualItem="let hotel" class="item-inner-hotel">
        <img src="{{hotel.hotelImage}}" class="htl-img">
        <h1 class="htl-name">{{hotel.hotelName}}</h1>
        <h3 class="htl-prc">{{hotel.hotelPrice}}</h3>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Edit4: Ionic info
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 6.5.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.1.2 browser 4.1.0 ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.0.1
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 6.0.0 
Node       : v6.10.2
npm        : 3.10.10 
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.1 Build version 8E1000a
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the `ts` file code too?

Comment: @Sampath, Please see edit2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use it as shown below.

**Note:** Since you're not using any custom components, you can use `ion-item` instead of `div`

*.html*

```
<ion-list [virtualScroll]="hotelsarray">

  <ion-item *virtualItem="let hotel">
    {{ hotel}}
  </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

Comment: Any console errors? Can you show how to bind it on your `code`? You didn't put that part on your question. Can you show the items of `hotelsarray`?

Comment: Please see my edit. I added more code. And no error in console at all.

Comment: Can you try without `img`?

Comment: I tried it already. I tried with ion-img too. And even tried with only h1 but same. Is virtualScroll works in ionic 3?

Comment: Did you do it for sample data? Just mocked your array with sample data and remove all your custom styles, now on the temple and use same exact code which I showed above.And see that.

Comment: So, here is the problem. I created totally new project & added a virtualScroll with hardcoded data, working fine. But then I also added module.ts file for lazy loading & problem arise.